# Headless Debian Server + Windows Clients + X11 Forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, vnc

I have a headless debian server that I SSH into regularly. I want to know how to set it up so that users can ssh in and then run something like iceweasel, and a window will popup on their machine which is the browser window. I don't want to install KDE or Gnome or anything like that on the server.

I have tightvncserver running on the server, and a vnc client on the windows machine. However, when I connect I get the following message:

> Xsession: X session started for myuser at Wed Mar 28 15:41:39 EDT 2012
> Xsession: unable to start X session --- no "/home/myuser/.xsession"
> file, no "/home/myuser/.Xsession" file, no session managers, no window
> managers, and no terminal emulators found; aborting.

What am I missing? I feel I am a bit confused with ssh+vnc, and how it all works together. Should the client use putty to connect first? then try and vnc in separately outside of putty? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install an X Windows server on your windows box. I recommend XMing http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/.

On your linux box, enable X11Forwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

When connecting to your server from Putty, click on Connection > SSH > X11 > Tick X11 Forwarding

Once you've logged in, you can test if it's working by running

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
```

Output should look like this

```
localhost:11.0
```

Then try run a GUI application

```
$ xclock
```